# How to check if device time is set correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am building a web app in which user when clicked on a button, I need to send the date time to my server. Unfortunately I don't have knowledge of `SSR` so I am using the Date Object of `javascript` to get date time. Suppose the user changes the time of his device, it can be Android,ios or Desktop then it won't be sending the correct date time to the server. I am sending data to server using Rest Api. It is possible to check if user has tampered with the date time on any device using `javascript`. I am using `create-react-app` template for my web app so I am fine with any react specific solution as well

Comment: Why not simply use the time on the server when it receives the request, rather than relying on the client to submit its own time?

Comment: Server time is the real time. Imagine your user was offline for a while and then the request _finally_ went through after a few hours of being offline. The user didn't tamper with their machine. Trust the server for anything. Client can be wrong for many reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot confirm the accuracy of time at the client so we should not use this to determine the current time. There are numerous reasons it could be inaccurate including manually changing the time in an attempt to manipulate results.

You should simply call the server and let the server track the time at the point the event was called - ideally UTC time.